# Testing workflows in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, workflow

I really love testing and building unit tests, but I find it quite annoying having to build tests for a website's workflow.

**e.g.**

**Register -> Check email -> Activate account -> Login**

or

**Login -> Edit details -> Submit and view profile**

---

**manual testing = loads of time + tireing**

even when using app such as Selenium, going though each iteration and then having to check emails etc...

---

Is there some way of performing an array of tests in a more efficient way?

**How do you guys do it? :**)

Answer (score 3):

I write "functional unit" tests for individual views using Django's test framework. I have found that integration tests are best done using something like [Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/). In one of my projects I came up with a minimal, custom implementation of [Ward Cunningham's FIT](http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?IntroductionToFit) mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a functional testing framework like [Cucumber](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/) (written in Ruby) or its Python equivalent, [Freshen](http://github.com/rlisagor/freshen). These allow you to write workflows in a plain-language text format, and the test runner will execute the steps and check the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the Lettuce framework for this kind of testing. You can find it here: http://lettuce.it/